# In Rails After upgrading Guard from 1.1 to 2.1.1, its not recognizing routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4, guard

Before the upgrade, everything worked fine. But after upgrading, its giving this error :

```
AuthenticationPages
  sign in page
    example at ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:9 (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

  1) AuthenticationPages sign in page
     Failure/Error: before { visit signin_path }
     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `signin_path' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_2::Nested_1:0x00000003f57488>
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:7:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # -e:1:in `<main>'

Finished in 0.00079 seconds
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:9 # AuthenticationPages sign in page
```

How can I fix this?